# How to deselect a radiobutton other than having it in a toggleGroup witth another radiobutton

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, radio-button, scenebuilder

I have 5 radiobutton (A,B,C,D,E), each 2 are in a toggle group(For example A and B are in a toggleGroup, C and D are in a toggleGroup), and the fifth one is alone. I want that if I selected A and C and then select E, both A and C are deselected. I tried using .setSelected(false) but it doesn't seem to work. Is there another function or can I have E in two toggleGroups? If yes, how?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like E shouldn't be a radio button at all - it should be a checkbox instead

Comment: It doesn't matter I just wanna know why setSelected isn't working.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. Include what version of JavaFX you're using.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better solution, but this solves your problem:
- Create event in *initialize* method for each *RadioButton* checking their values (and add your code according to their selection status):

```
aRadioButton.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    //if RadioButton is selected
    if (newValue) {
        //check if other RadioButtons are selected
        if(bRadioButton.isSelected()) {
             //add your code
             // deselect it using:
             bRadioButton.setSelected(false);
        } else {
        // aRadioButton is deselected
        //add your code
     }
}
```

- Or create an event from fxml

```
@FXML
private void aRadioButton(ActionEvent event) { 
    //this will change the state of RadioButton
    //to preserve deselection from this event use:
    if(!aRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        aRadioButon.setSelected(true);    
    }
    //add your code here
}
```

> This way doesn't include a *ToggleGroup* and you have to manage RadioButton's selection status.